# h2database as git repo

Tags: git, github, h2

I like H2 very much! Also I like and use git.
I failed to convert svn repository to git repo, so I downloaded sources and push them to [github](https://github.com/dector/h2database).

**BUT** It would be very great if you'll publish h2 sources in git repo (using github). And I'll delete my "fork" and will fork your github repo. I would like to read sources and try to make few commits.

Thanks!

Comment: such a question doesn't belong here. why don't you write a mail to the author?

Comment: Сause, i _didn't_ find it. There is no private messages on stackoverflow. So, I asked here. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the [Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/h2-database?pli=1) instead of posting here. StackOverflow is for questions, it's not a mail system or a mailing list :-)

By the way, [your comment on Github](https://github.com/dector/h2database) is strange: you wrote "I just FORKED it." Is it really your intention to *fork* it, meaning you want to [start independent development on it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28software_development%29)? You only 'forked' one part of the source code by the way. Not the documentation.